# How to maintaing history of inserts and update in both column and table wise?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I had asked earlier in SO, how to wrap the multiple column  in single column, regarding the same, but i picked up another approach and done that part. Now the requirement has been slightly changed and become, if any of the field in table is update then the query or trigger will be able to detect - on what table has and what columns.

**Update**

For example I have table tblAddress having column Address, WorkPhone, CellPhone, City, State etc. If a user updates WorkPhone then the query should be able to detect that in table address phone number has been updated and the message will be inserted to another table called tblHistory where tblHistory is mine audit-trail maintaining table and tblAddress is where insert update or delete operation will be performed.

Comment: "I hope my query is clear..." - it is not....

Comment: Please go ahead.. which part is not clear...i will explain

Comment: I'm afraid all of it is unclear.

Comment: So are you looking for some way of auditing all the changes to the data in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two basic patterns you can use:

1. Store all of the column values in a history table (e.g. tblAddress_History) for each audited table (e.g. tblAddress) when a row in the audited table is updated. Each history table would basically mirror the schema of its corresponding audited table (plus maybe a comment or audit info such as when and by whom the update was made).
2. Store a separate row for individual columns in a history table (e.g. tblHistory) for all audited tables; when a row is updated you'd need to create a separate row in the history table for each column that is updated. Your history table would then need to include columns to identify the audited table and the updated column.

Comment: +1 for option number 1.. Unless there are some massive amount of data in the tables I would go for the simple solution.

Comment: Thanks but the scenario you have suggested is valid for single table. I need a dynamic solution , my frontend is ASP.Net with C# , where in any table if insert or update or delete events occurs then the audit trail will be maintained in history table.

Comment: The second solution I outlined can work for any number of tables, hence my qualification "Your history table would then need to include columns to identify the audited table and the updated column." And you can implement the auditing in your ASP.NET C# code or you could implement it (in several different ways) in your backend SQL Server code.